# Automatically generate PDBs with dotPeek

Tags: dotpeek

I just discovered dotPeek and its symbol server greatness. The only drawback for me currently is that I need to manually add each DLL I want to debug and manually generate the PDB for it. It would be excellent if I could either do this in batch and just generate PDBs for a whole directory, or automatically generate them when requested in the symbol server (and the DLL is in the assembly explorer or something). Or another way to automate more of it. Is any of that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I've found, which will probably work for me, is to set the "Generate symbol files for" option in Tools > Options > Symbol Server to "Assemblies opened in the Assembly Explorer". This seems to automatically find anything in the explorer and generate a PDB on the fly **if** you open dotPeek **and** start the symbol server **before** you start Visual Studio.